# Code to ignore the Case of Alphabets

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code. What i want is the code should ignore the case of alphabets whether it is small capital or both.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, row As ListRow

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table2")

Dim intValueToFind As String, intValueToFind1 As String, rng As Range, rng1 As Range

Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
Set rng1 = tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange


intValueToFind = LCase(Me.ComboBox1.Value)
intValueToFind1 = LCase(Me.TextBox2.Value)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then

    For Each rng In rng
        If LCase(rng.Value) = intValueToFind Then
            If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
                For Each rng1 In rng1
                    If LCase(rng1.Value) = intValueToFind1 Then
                        MsgBox ("Group Head under this Account Head already Exist. Please enter the Unique Name...")
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Next rng1
            End If
        End If
    Next rng

End If


Set row = tbl.ListRows.Add
row.Range(1, 1).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
row.Range(1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
End Sub
```

kindly review the above code and advise where i am mistaking.

Comment: What is the issue? Are you getting any errors? If so, what is the error and in which line it happens?

Comment: There is no error. It is not ignoring the case of aplhabets

Comment: It look like you problem is you ranges (rather than your casing) - what value are you getting for the first iteration for `rng1.Value`? `For Each rng In rng` gives you one iteration - like saying "for each America in America" - there's only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast both sides to lower case (or upper case):

```
If LCase(rng.Value) = LCase(intValueToFind) Then
```

Comment: Honest question: If OP is already assigning `intValueToFind = LCase(Me.ComboBox1.Value)` why does he/she needs to cast `LCase(intValueToFind)` again in here?

Comment: @Excel Developers It solved my problem. Will you please explain a little bit the purpose of doing this...

Comment: @Victor: good question. I hadn't noticed that, and so yes you are right, it shouldn't be necessary to cast again.

Comment: Ok, now I'm really curious. If OP had already assigned the value to the variable as `LCase`, how come this answer solved their problem? What's the difference between passing the value to the variable as `LCase` and comparing both sides in lower case. `intValueToFind` should already be in lower case at this point. What is being missed here? Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to criticize your answer or anything like that. I'm just genuinely baffled here trying to figure this out

Comment: Me too. Looking at the code in OP I don't see why it shouldn't work. @Salman are you sure you're original code didn't work?

Comment: Yes i am sure before it was not working after u suggested me change it worked

Comment: That's weird. Anyway, I notice you use "For Each rng in rng". That is not a good idea. Use a separate range variable, e.g. "For Each r in rng".